# Manager isn't accessible via Blog instances

Tags: python, django, mongodb, sqlite

I am using Django(1.5.4), Python(2.7), sqlite3.

I want to save my user details in sqlite3 database. My code is like this;

This is models.py file.

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my views.py file

```
def shiva(request):
    b = Blog(name='Itons Blog', tagline='All the best to Iton team')
    b.save()
    print [e.name for e in b.objects.all()]
    return HttpResponse("saved")
```

When i am trying to save the details in sqlite3 the error is coming as;

`AttributeError at / Manager isn't accessible via Blog instances`

Comment: I got the answer by keeping this,  "print [e.name for e in Blog.objects.all()]" .Just kept Blog in place of b.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
print [e.name for e in b.objects.all()]  # won't work
```

`b` is a `Blog` instance, which will not access the objects Manager. You might try this instead (if you want all rows, which it appears you do since you are creating a list from multiple names):

```
print [e.name for e in Blog.objects.all()]
```

Note the use of `Blog` instead of `b` in `Blog.objects.all()`. The objects manager is not accessible via `b` but is accessible via the class `Blog`.

For further explanation (using an example much like yours), [see the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects).

Comment: I got the answer by keeping this: print [e.name for e in Blog.objects.all()] Just kept `Blog` in place of b.

Answer (score 3):

`b.objects.all()` should be `Blog.objects.all()` because the manager (objects) must be accessed from the model class not instances.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the error says, the Manager (`.objects`) is only available from the Blog class, not from its instances.

But it's not clear what you are trying to do. What are you expecting the list comprehension to return?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I can access my table by changing the object name 'b' to 'Blog'.